# Capitalize specific words on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have your typical MVC3 app with lots of CRUD pages. And in these pages there are lots of lists with Id columns... The client told me today that they always want to see "ID" instead of "Id" but the fields are usually more fully qualified (IE: "Job Id" or something)

Is there a way, with css, to text transform ONLY the "Id" part of the text (to all caps) without adding any extra html?

I think part of the solution involves this pseudo class: div:contains(" Id ") but I'm not sure if it's even do-able...

Also I don't mind doing this w/ jquery, but I'm trying to minimize refactoring.

Comment: please show a relevant snippet of HTML

Comment: Is 'Id' the only text you need to change?

Comment: the problem really should be taken care of prior to the browser.

Comment: I don't consider it a problem... This framework does a lot of model driven design and I like "Id" better than "ID"... I consider this only a visual thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the other answers here is the short version with valid replacement:

```
$("h3").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\b(id)\b/gi, "ID");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bcAyP/

Comment: Nice. Gotta sharpen up on my regex!

Comment: FYI, the parens are superfluous. +1 for using the proper functional form of `text()`. Note, however, that this will still destroy any other inline markup that may be present in the `<h3>`.

Comment: You really know how to push us Phrogz, the regex police ;) This serves as a reminder that regex and html really don't mix.

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply a CSS style to a single word, only to elements. This means that you'll need to have additional HTML. Otherwise, it can be done in jQuery.

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    title = title.replace(/\bid\b/gi, "ID");
    $(this).text(title);
});
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKYg7/16/)

Comment: will that also transform inner matches? like..id in "could this be stupid"?

Comment: +1 for a correct statement about CSS, -1 for an imprecise regex and code that can and will destroy any sub-markup inside an element.

Comment: Yikes. I did that a little too fast. Thanks for the feedback guys, updated code and example.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply CSS to specific words, only elements (or the small set of pseudo-elements defined by CSS). Here's a JavaScript-based solution that never affects your markup:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6LRWC/2/

```
function replaceTextUnder(node,pattern,str){
  var t, walk=document.createTreeWalker(node,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(t=walk.nextNode()){
    t.nodeValue = t.nodeValue.replace(pattern,str);
  }
}

replaceTextUnder(document.body, /\bid\b/gi, "ID" );
```

Alternatively, here it is wrapped up as a jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.replaceInText = function(pattern,str){
  return this.each(function(){
    var t, walk=document.createTreeWalker(this,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(t=walk.nextNode()) t.nodeValue = t.nodeValue.replace(pattern,str);
  });
};

$('li,td,th').replaceInText( /\bid\b/gi, "ID" );​
```

Comment: No need to crawl the whole document. Just h3 elements :S

Comment: @Zenph Where do you see that requirement?

Comment: " lists with Id columns" You should really read questions/answers more closely. There it certainly no need to crawl the whole document. At most whatever the columns are wrapped in. Be it th or h3.

Comment: @Zenph I'm not sure where you get h3 from (other than other answers here), but a) it's *fast* to walk the entire document with a tree walker, and b) I've abstracted the function to be able to be applied to any node.

Comment: First my comment was on the original answer you submitted so obviously it doesn't reflect your update. The h3 is from the assumption than the columns are wrapped in column headers, naturally. Whether that be h3, or th, or whatever else is used. Thanks for introducing me to TreeWalker, anyway.

Comment: @Zenph You're welcome. :) My only point was that I am hard-pressed to imagine a situation where an <h3> would be used to head up a column. Thank you, though, for the impetus to make my solution properly re-usable and targeted to specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

To combat the inner matches, use something like this:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\sId/g, "ID"));
});​
```

This of course assumes that id is always capitalized as in your description.

Comment: -1 Consider the impact on `<h3>This <em>is</em> stupid ident "id".</h3>`.

Comment: (1) It will destroy the `<em>`. (2) It will match `ident`. (3) It will not match `"id"`. (Hint for 2 and 3: `\b`)

Comment: you should read the code properly. I'm not even matching 'id', I'm matching 'Id', which follows a space. It won't match any of those. But I see what you mean, it calls for a more robust regex.

Comment: You have a `/i` on your regex, it will match them. Further, it will destroy the space (e.g. turning "stupid ident" into "stupidIDent"). Test it and see :) http://jsfiddle.net/VKYg7/15/

Comment: Of course :) I think it requires a better regex regardless and I lack the regex skills.

Comment: `.replace(/\bid\b/gi,'ID')` will fix the main problems (but not the markup destroying).

Comment: Solution is down at the bottom submitted by VisioN.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HZVs8/

Here you go sir.

```
$("body").html(function(i, t) {
return t.replace(/( id)/g, " ID");
});​
```

What you have to watch out for with this, is that you have to make sure the "id" has a space before it in the jQuery, otherwise, this code with find EVERY string of text that has "id" in it an convert it to "ID".

If if the issue you are having is that the text is like this: "ProjectId" and you want it like this: "ProjectID" then use this code:

```
$("body").html(function(i, t) {
return t.replace(/(Id)/g, " ID");
});
```

Basically, the text you are selecting is case sensitive. Just make sure you are selecting the right snippet or it may select every word with "id" and make it "ID" and you don't want that.

Mess around with the JSFiddle I made. It works.

Comment: -1 You are removing the space from the document, and not testing to ensure that this is not something like "my identity".